# Change MIME type of csv file to application/octet-stream

Tags: oauth2-playground

How to Change MIME type of csv file to application/octet-stream from `application/vnd.ms-excel`, becouse I can uplaoad a csv file:
Content-type: `application/octet-stream`

```
daily_upload = analytics.management().dailyUploads().upload(
```

===============1922165529==

```
Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel - 
{"error":{"errors":[{"domain":"global","reason":"badContent","message":"Unsupported content with type: application/octet-stream"}],"code":400,"message":"Unsupported content with type: application/octet-stream"}}
```